# Calculating minutes from two different format time

Tags: sql-server-2008, time

> My DB values save in this format

`"12:07 AM"`

> dataType `varchar` in Sql Server
>
> i want minutes b/w 2 times  2nd time is
>   current time

```
23:50 AM
23:24:43.6100000
differnce 26 minutes
```

> but output come in negative values by executing below query
>   here m trying to do but output come in negative values

```
select datediff(minute,cast(getdate() as time),OrderDeliverTime)
    from tblOrder
```

Comment: You have placed the current time first in the datediff, so you are getting the difference in time as a negative value.

Comment: same values come -1396

Answer (score 1):

If the OrderDeliverTime occurs in the past, then it should be the middle parameter in DateDiff:

```
select datediff(minute,OrderDeliverTime,cast(getdate() as time)) from tblOrder
```

Comment: yup u ri8 minutes is now coming positive values but not accurate difference it will show 1356   i want accurate current i put diference 26 minutes but it shown 1356

Comment: :O sql get in 24 digit clock but my sql save value in 12 digit clock how to make timepicker to 24 digit clock

Comment: issued solved some little mistake :P m using datetimepicker as 12 hour format and sql 24 hour format so now m removing my question because its not question which help any body